# Projections in the Cuntz algebra which have the same $K_0$ class

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Assume that $e,f$ are two projections in the  Cuntz algebra $\mathcal{O}_n$  , which have the  same $K_0$ class. Are they necessarily Murray von Neumann equivalent ?

The following post is  the  motivation of this question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300095/is-every-nontrivial-idempotent-in-the-cuntz-algebra-a-commutator-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For two projections $p,q\in A$, equivalence in $K_0(A)$ is always Murray-von Neumann equivalence. One usually defines $K_0$-equivalence to occur in the biggest of the matrix algebras containing the projections; in this case both $p,q\in M_1(A)$, so $K_0$ equivalence gives $v\in A$ with $v^*v=p$, $vv^*=q$.

And this is coherent with looking at things "higher up". If we now see the projections as 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \begin{bmatrix}q&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and they are equivalent in $M_2(A)$, it means that there exists $V\in M_2(A)$ with 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=V^*V=\begin{bmatrix}V_{11}^*V_{11}+V_{21}^*V_{21}&V_{11}^*V_{12}+V_{21}^*V_{22}\\V_{12}^*V_{11}+V_{22}^*V_{21}&V_{12}^*V_{12}+V_{22}^*V_{22}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
From the 2,2 entry we get $V_{12}=V_{22}=0$.  Similarly, from
$$
\begin{bmatrix}q&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=VV^*=\begin{bmatrix}V_{11}V_{11}^*+V_{12}V_{12}^*&V_{11}V_{21}^*+V_{12}V_{22}^*\\V_{21}V_{11}^*+V_{22}V_{12}^*&V_{21}V_{21}^*+V_{22}V_{22}^*\end{bmatrix},
$$
we now see from the 2,2 entry that  $V_{21}=0$. Thus $p=V_{11}^*V_{11}$, $q=V_{11}V_{11}^*$ are Murray-von Neumann equivalent.

Note that the same argument works if $p\oplus 0_m$ is equivalent to $q \oplus 0_m$ for $m>1$.

Comment: Thanks  for this  answer. what is  my  mistake in the  following: Please  read the  comment  conversation to the  linked  MO  post: In the  language  of  vector  bundles  two  non isomorphic  bundles  can be  stably isomorphic. This means  that two idempotent can  be  non equivalent but in the  next  matrix  size they are equivalent. as I  learned from "very  basic  NCG by  Masoud  khalkhali, isomorphic  bundles gives  Murray  Von  neuman  equivalents  Idemptotents. So  I think that there  are  contradictory  situation.

Comment: I don't really know what you expect me to get from those comments. It is standard that $e\simeq e\oplus 0$, so if you have $e\oplus 0\simeq f\oplus 0$, then $$e\simeq e\oplus 0\simeq f\oplus 0\simeq f.$$

Comment: I mean that I am leading to  apparently a  contradictory  situation. and  I ask you to help me to remove my  misunderstanding: from one hand  I  completely understand  your interesting answer. on the  other  hand  the  comment  in the  MO  link remind  me  of  the  following  situation: a  vector  bundle  corresond  to a  projection(or  idempotent). Murray  von Neumann equivalents correspond  to isomorphic  bundle  while similarity  corresponds to  isomorphic  bundles  with isomorphic  complented bundle.

Comment: So if  a  two  non isomorphic  bundle  are  stably isomorphic, the  algebraic  analogy would  be  the  following: two  non Murray  equivalent projections can have  Murray  equivalence  stabilization! On the  other hand your  answer says it is impossible!

Comment: So the  situation is  interesting for me, apparently a  contradictory situation. what is  my  mistake?

Comment: Could  I declare  what  is  my  misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry, but my knowledge of vector bundles is less than superficial, so I cannot comment at all on such analogy. If you give me a concrete statement about C$^*$/von Neumann algebras, I can try to make sense of it, but without one I don't have much to say.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I think you're confusion comes from an understanding of the correspondence between vector bundles and projections.  For a compact Hausdorff space $X$, and a projection $p\in M_n(C(X))\cong C(X,M_n(\mathbb C))$, the corresponding bundle $\xi_p$ is $\{(x,v)\in X\times \mathbb C^n:v\in \operatorname{Im}p(x)\}$, which isn't necessarily a rank $n$ bundle.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Although we have a correspondence between projections and vector bundles, we don't have a correspondence between the rank of the vector bundle and the dimension of the matrix algebra.

Comment: @Aweygan  Thanks  for  your  comment. Yes the rank is  the  trace of the idempotent. But I try  to  explain my  confusion in details. I will come back very soon.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. For $A = \mathcal O_2$ it fails for example. Indeed $K_0(\mathcal O_2) = \{0\}$ but not all  projections are equivalent.

I guess Martin shows that there is an inclusion $\mathrm{Proj}(A)  / \sim_\mathrm{MvN} \ \hookrightarrow \ V(A)$.

Comment: Could you please provide a proof (or at least a reference) of the claims you make?  Additionally, what is $V(A)$?

Comment: $V(A)$ is the Murray-von Neumann monoid given by $\bigcup_{\mathbb N} \mathrm{Proj}_n(A) / \sim_{\mathrm{MvN}}$. Furthermore, $0$ and $1$ are projections in $\mathcal O_2$ with the same $K_0$-class.

Comment: @AndréS.  Both projections are equivalent to 1. What are non equivalence projections you indicated in your answer?

Comment: Thanks.  Equivalence in $K_0$ is stable equivalence.  Don't know what I was thinking.